# Can angle congruence be defined from betweenness and segment congruence?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, model-theory

This question was inspired by Tarski's axiom set for geometry. Let our universe of discourse be $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $B$ be the ternary betweenness relation on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $C$ be the $4$-ary relation where $C(x,y,z,w)$ holds iff the distance from point $x$ to point $y$ is the same as the distance from point $z$ to point $w$. My question is, using $B$ and $C$, is it possible to define the relation of angle congruence? More precisely, let $R$ be the $6$-ary relation such that $R(x,y,z,x',y',z')$ holds iff

1. $x,y,z$ are distinct noncollinear points
2. $x',y',z'$ are also distinct noncollinear points
3. Angle $\angle xyz$ is congruent to angle $\angle x'y'z'$

My precise question is, is $R$ definable by a first-order formula in the structure $(\mathbb{R}^2; B,C)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: you can use side-side-side triangle congruence.  Two angles $\angle abc$ and $\angle def$ are congruent iff there exist $a'$ between $a$ and $b$, $c'$ between $b$ and $c$, $d'$ between $d$ and $e$, and $f'$ between $e$ and $f$ such that the pairwise distances between $a',b,$ and $c'$ are all equal to the corresponding pairwise distances between $d',e,$ and $f'$.